# How to detect mobile device and get user agent info send and save that information to database on server, only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-website, mobile-devices, wurfl

Is there any script to check user agent then send and save that information to database on server?

I'm making mobile website with 2 versions like *m.facebook.com* and *touch.facebook.com* and I want to redirect to different mobiles. and I use **WURFL** device detection.

So for example m.html5version.com should be delivered to all HTML5 supported devices and *m.mobileversion.com* should deliver to all other mobiles.

So i need a way to detect device and browser 1st time using any server-side or client-side method. when any user will open the website first time on device then an script should run once it should collect the information about device and browser and should save the information in my existing WURFL database , so next time when any user will come from same device then he will redirect to touch or mobile version of website depending on device.

So only 1st time on 1st device I want to detect device and save the info.

Is there any way to do this?

**For example**

Android 1.6 doesn't have HTML5 support and still in use. So i want to redirect all Android 1.6 devices to *m.mobileversion.com* not to *touch.mobileversion.com*

And in touch version of website I'm using HTML 5 tags like `<header>`, `<footer>`, `<nav>` etc which is not supported Android 1.6. So i want to detect the first device who will access the website from Android 1.6 device and because HTML5 is not supported in 1.6 so user agent should be saved in my database then I when next time any user will open the website in 1.6 it will redirect to lo-fi mobile version automatically, no detection should be needed 2nd time for any device.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

see below link, this will perfectly suitable for your need

### http://detectmobilebrowser.com

below is one more script :

### http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look into jQuery's take on this, since it's interesting.

In addition to detecting the browser, they detect browser features:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

Also, keep in mind that some mobile users don't want to be redirected to the mobile-optimized device. I, for one, positively hate it when a site detects my iPad as a mobile device and sends me (without any possibility to override it) to a sloppy mobile site that I wouldn't even want to browse with an iPhone.

iOS and Android devices, in general, will happily work with the standard site if it's coded properly. And other mobile phones are quickly dying.

Comment: I don't want to detect iPad as a mobile device. I consider iPad as Desktop when I make website

Comment: Android 1.6 doesn't have HTML5 support and still in use. So i want to redirect all Android 1.6 devices to m.mobileversion.com not to touch.mobileversion.com

Comment: I'd make the argument that iPhone/Android should be considered such as well, unless your website is an application with UI elements that need to be manipulated. The thing to avoid is flexible width content. If you've a fixed 480-640px content width, the zoom feature is enough for iPhone/Android to browse the site comfortably.

Answer (score 0):

As far as only detecting and saving the data once, you can set a cookie to record the fact that you've already done the detection. Then the next time a page is loaded, check to see if the cookie exists -- if it doesn't, then call your detection function and record to the database. If you do find the cookie, then you know you've already collected the data and you can skip doing it again.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: But I want to detect one mobile once for all users in  the world