# Javascript code to find the user device

Tags: javascript, jquery, device-detection

I wrote some simple code to find the type of the device:

```
$(document).ready(detectDevice);

function detectDevice() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
        var device = "Desktop";

        console.log('=======device======', device);
    } else if (window.innerWidth < 767 && window.innerWidth > 481) {
        var device = "iPad";
    } else if (window.innerWidth < 480) {
        var device = "Mobile Phone";
    }
}
```

But I want to find the correct model name of the device from which the app is being used. I don't want to write the code using `navigator.userAgent` which will find out using browsers.

Please can someone tell me if there is any way to find this using JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: You don't want to use navigator.userAgent then what you want exactly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect mobile device and get user agent info send and save that information to database on server, only once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081346/how-to-detect-mobile-device-and-get-user-agent-info-send-and-save-that-informati)

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400489/ipad-version-detection-in-javascript) for iPads.

Comment: navigator.userAgent will findout the device based on browser right. But I wont run my application on browser. So, I want some other way to find the device.

Comment: https://github.com/matthewhudson/device.js this small client script does that just for you - check it out.

Comment: No. That is based on mobile browser @hjpotter92

Comment: Can you please explain how can i make use of device.js @MartinWebb

Comment: If you check the link the script comes with clear instructions, in your case you can look at the code and it shows you exactly how the programmer identifies the devices, the script may fit your needs or it may give you the info you need to make your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lightweight libary to do this

https://github.com/matthewhudson/current-device

Here is how it works:

```
  console.log("device.portrait() === %s", device.portrait());
  console.log("device.landscape() === %s", device.landscape());
  console.log("device.mobile() === %s", device.mobile());
  console.log("device.tablet() === %s", device.tablet());
  console.log("device.ipad() === %s", device.ipad());
  console.log("device.ipod() === %s", device.ipod());
  console.log("device.iphone() === %s", device.iphone());
  console.log("device.android() === %s", device.android());
  console.log("device.androidTablet() === %s", device.androidTablet());
  console.log("device.blackberryTablet() === %s", device.blackberryTablet());
  console.log("device.fxos() === %s", device.fxos());
  console.log("device.fxosPhone() === %s", device.fxosPhone());
  console.log("device.fxosTablet() === %s", device.fxosTablet());
```

**Test for Ipad**

```
  if (device.ipad()) //....do something
```

Comment: This seems hard to maintain. There are so many devices in the world; how could you even track them all?