# How do I make the mobile view of my website not show certain elements?

Tags: html, css, mobile

On my website, currently when you load it, it plays a video automatically then fades in to the website. But due to mobile phone data rules, it cannot automatically play on phones. How do I make the video not even show up on mobile views? Will it to with the CSS @media ?

Comment: Yes, target the html element that contains the video using media queries and selecting `display: none;`

Comment: I would use https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect - that way it won't load. Using css (display:none) with media queries or without still loads it, but it's just not visible.

Comment: Mobile includes tablets that equal resolutions that match desktops, so using CSS is not the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least two options:

1.Detect mobile browser with JavaScript. Link here:
[javascript - How to detect mobile device and get user agent info send and save that information to database on server, only once? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081346/how-to-detect-mobile-device-and-get-user-agent-info-send-and-save-that-informati) 

2. Use @media queries. Link here:
[How To Use CSS3 Media Queries To Create a Mobile Version of Your Website | Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to wrap it in a class (for the sake of this example, I'll call it `show-desktop`.

Here is how you would structure your media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
  .show-desktop{
     display:none;
   }
}
```

This makes the contents of the class `show-desktop` hidden when the size of the device is 767 pixels or smaller.